# AWS aurora db configuration with quarkus

Tags: amazon-rds, quarkus, amazon-aurora

How to configure and connect to **AWS aurora** db with  **quarkus**? Is there any reactive client for it ? And what are the minimum application properties to be configured for the same?

My db endpoint is - `empdbinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`
and port is default port `3306`

Answer (score 0):

AWS Aurora is either [MySQL or PostgreSQL compatible](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/), depending on which option you choose when configuring your DB instance. So you are able to connect just as you would to a [normal MySQL or PostgreSQL DB](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource).